# Support URL not used for iTunes Connect?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Today I uploaded my app onto App Store and the support URL is no where to be found. Instead only my Marketing URL is used as the Developer Website on my app store page. So what's the point of having a Support URL if that's not found on my app store page?

I would really prefer that Developer Website be my Support URL that has my official website instead of Marketing URL that has twitter account. How do I fix this?

Comment: I just looked at an app that's currently in review and it shows slots for both the Marketing URL and the Support URL.  But it's not on the App Store page, it's on the Version page.

Comment: I'm NOT talking about iTunes Connect, I'm talking about App Store. I'm saying that in App Store on my app page under "Developer Website", they used the Marketing URL instead of my support URL. I thought they were supposed to use Support URL for Developer Website.